# How to receive Csv file from android using c# wcf and save to server

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf

I an using a asp.net 2010 and I have a wcf web service.
I want to receive the csv file from android and save the receive file to the folder in my server.

The android part is sending the .Csv file using bytes.

Does anyone has an idea how to receive the .Csv file?

I have this code for a method "POST" called by android app.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/upload?filename={filename}",
        Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        wsResponse UploadFile(string filename, System.IO.Stream fileContent);
```

and what will be my next code.. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right. You've got the stream.

Now use a CSV parsing library to parse the CSV. For example http://www.filehelpers.com/
And execute whatever logic you need to do.

A sample (You'll need to reference the filehelpers library) -

```
     [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public class YourTypeForCSV
    {
        public string Field1;
        public int Field2;
    }


    void UploadFile(string filename, System.IO.Stream fileContent)
    {
        FileHelperEngine<YourTypeForCSV> engine = new FileHelperEngine<YourTypeForCSV>();

        YourTypeForCSV[] records = engine.ReadStream(new StreamReader(fileContent));

        // .. do whatever you need
    }
```

Comment: How will i do it programmatically

Comment: @user3463171 not sure what do you mean but added a code sample now.